# python read files and stop when a condition satisfies

Tags: python

I am trying a program where it reads all files in a directory and when the 'color=brown' is attained then my program has to stop reading even if finds 'color=brown' in the next file.I mean,the condition first met should only be taken.

I tried a program where it prints all the color=brown from all the files,but i have to stop after its first read. Please help!

```
import os
path = r'C:\Python27' 
data = {}


for dir_entry in os.listdir(path):
    dir_entry_path = os.path.join(path, dir_entry)
    if os.path.isfile(dir_entry_path):
        with open(dir_entry_path, 'r') as my_file:
            for line in my_file:
                for part in line.split():
                    if "color=brown" in part:
                        print part
```

please help!answers will be appreciated!

Comment: `break` statement? Is that what you need?

Comment: yes i think so,please help me to apply it!

Comment: you can also make it a  function and just `return part`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the break statement.

```
...
    if "color=brown" in part:
        print part
        # set some variable to check at the last thing before your other for loops
        # turnover.
        br = True
        break
```

and then use that to break out of every other two for loops you've initiated.

```
    if br == True:
        break
    else:
        pass
if br == True:
    break
else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 3):

you can set a variable stating that you are done and then break out of each loop
but depending on the nesting of the loop it might be cleaner to use an exception to jump out of the loop (kind of like a goto in C):

```
try:
    for m in range(10):
        for n in range(10):
            if m == 5 and n == 15: 
                raise StopIteration
except StopIteration:
    print "found"
else:
    print "not found"
print "always runs unless the other clauses return"
```